# Using X,Y Coords With A Bitmap Image

Tags: c++, bitmap, coordinates

I have a c/c++ program running on my Linux box that loads up a 24bit bitmap, reads the two headers and then stores the image data into a char* variable. I have verified this works by dumping that variables contents into a raw binary file and compared it to the original bitmap+offset. I used the code from [HERE](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/how-to-load-a-bitmap-r1966) and unmodified and takes care or reordering into RGB and bottom up.

Now if I have a list of coordinates like X, Y, Width, Height how the heck do I translate these into the byte offsets of my image?!

In [MY CODE](http://pastebin.com/G7DhMRzV) you see that I am calculating the width of one scanline and the glyph location to find Y and then adding a scanline for each y+1. Similarly for X I am iterating over by three bytes at a time. And finally I store those three bytes sequentially into my temporary character array.

In truth I do not need the pixel data as the glyph is a 0xFF or 0x00 with no smoothing. I included it to make sure my bits where accounted for.

[HERE](http://www.flickr.com/photos/90883337@N02/8255838800/in/photostream) is the image I am using.

EDIT: --------------------------------------------

As mentioned below my math was a bit quarky. fixed the line in the i,j,k loop to:

```
tmpChar[i][j][k] = img.data[(((Y+j) * imgWidth) + (X + i)) * imgBPP + k];
```

As for my programs output [HERE](http://pastebin.com/SgFe80MF) as you can see it loads the bitmap fine and the header info is proper but when I try to display the contents of the tmpChar array its all 0xFF (I used a signed int so 0xFF = -1 and 0x00 = +0)

Comment: I guess, since you are asking, your code doesn't work as expected. What does it output? Meanwhile, i guess an answer.

Comment: @anatolyg see my edit above

Answer (score 1):

The layout in memory of the image is (ignoring that I might have reversed R, G and B):

```
[R of pixel 0]  [G of pixel 0] [B of pixel 0] ....... [B of (0, imgWidth-1)] [R of pixel (1, 0)] .....
```

So to calculate the offset of any given pixel: `offset = ((Y * imgWidth) + X) * imgBPP + colorByte`.

Giving for your inner loop, as far as I can tell and assuming your X and Y for the character are correct:

```
tmpChar[i][j][k] = img.data[(((Y+j) * imgWidth) + (x + i)) * imgBPP + k];
```

Comment: Oh boy I had some strange polynomial in my equation lol All the right pieces but needed to bring my constants out of the brackets. Your code snippit indeed loads the pixels in the correct fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the pixels are stored in a upside-down order in memory, as is usual with [BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format):

> Normally pixels are stored "upside-down" with respect to normal image
>   raster scan order, starting in the lower left corner, going from left
>   to right, and then row by row from the bottom to the top of the image

So your code may be reading the wrong block of pixels.

Comment: The bmp loading code I used automatically corrects the pixel reversal and the bottop up methods already.